# Why can't I sum these lists? It only returns the first answer, but if I print I can get it to print all answers instead? Thanks :)

Tags: python

This is the code that I have so far. I don't understand why it would work with print but not as a return function?

```py
# Setup
import numpy as np

data_string = input("Enter elements of a list separated by space")
data = data_string.split()


# Function
def sumrescubed(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] = float(data[i])

    data_sum = sum(data)
    mean = sum(data) / len(data)

    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        answer_sum = sum([(data[i] - mean) ** 3])

    return answer_sum


sumrescubed(data)
```

Comment: Please re-format the code, you people can understand the function and your intent.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please format your code properly as well as explain what you're trying to do.   What does the data look like?   What is your expected output?

Comment: Incidentally,  arrays in python are zero-based, so right now with your ```for i in range(1, len(data))``` you're missing the first entry

Comment: what is the purpose of ```answer_sum = ...```?

Comment: The second `for` loop sets `answer_sum` to a new value every time through the loop, discarding the previous value.  So `answer_sum` ends up as only the final value from the loop.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do is make `answer_sum` a list, and append each cube to it so that you can return the list of individual items (which are what you're seeing when you `print(answer_sum) within the loop in your current code`):

```
        answer_sum = []
        for i in data:
            answer_sum.append((i - mean)**3)
        
        return answer_sum
```

I'd suggest simplifying the whole thing by using comprehensions instead of iterating over the lists by index:

```
def sumrescubed(data):
    nums = [float(i) for i in data]
    mean = sum(nums) / len(nums)
    return [(i - mean)**3 for i in nums]
```